# How do I get the symmetric key (session key) established during SSL/TLS handshake to encrypt/decrypt messages?

Tags: java, android-studio, ssl, encryption

I am creating a chat application in Android Studio that uses TLS to secure communication between server and client. One device is server and one is client and I am programming in Java. I have established a connection, and the handshake is performed. I am using ECDHE_ECDSA_AES256_GCM_SHA256. How do I get the keys established during the handshake to use in AES for encryption/decryption of data path messages? Is this something that is done in the background, or do I actually have to implement the establishment of keys?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
public Message(PublicKey to, PublicKey from, String message, PrivateKey privateKey) {
   this.to = to;
   this.from = from;

   Cipher cipher = null;
   try {
       cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Constants.ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM_AES);
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, to);
       this.ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      
       // Signature
       ByteArrayOutputStream signatureStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       signatureStream.write(to.getEncoded());
       signatureStream.write(from.getEncoded());
       signatureStream.write(this.ciphertext);

       Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(Constants.SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
       signature.initSign(privateKey);
       signature.update(signatureStream.toByteArray());
       this.signature = signature.sign();
       this.plaintext = message;

   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IOException | SignatureException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This is the exception that I get:

```
2021-03-23 08:57:04.278 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No provider offers [AES, GCM, NoPadding] for EC key of class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey and export format X.509
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.279 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2922)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.279 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.279 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.279 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.280 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.280 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.models.Message.<init>(Message.java:53)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.280 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.activities.ChatActivity.sendMessage(ChatActivity.java:186)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.281 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.activities.ChatActivity.lambda$setupUI$0$ChatActivity(ChatActivity.java:167)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.281 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.activities.-$$Lambda$ChatActivity$ISUZTD0SoBMpbbVEzHtgcAyds9E.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.281 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.281 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.282 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.282 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.282 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.282 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.283 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.283 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.283 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.283 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.284 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    2021-03-23 08:57:04.284 24162-24162/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: What is the issue you are faccing? Any error?

Comment: I have created certificates using ECDSA, and therefore have EC private and public keys. I wish to encrypt/decrypt messages to send between client and server after the ssl handshake. I am not sure which keys to use for data path encryption/decryption. I get this error when I try to use the EC keys with AES (understandably). I edited the post with the exception, and also how I tried to encrypt messages.

Comment: why do you try to do all those things yourself? Can't you just use [SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm) ?

Comment: There is no TLS in the code you present. You get an error because you try to init a AES cipher with a EC public key. AES ciphes needs AES keys. TLS session keys are not ment for you to use

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I want to specify which encryption algorithm to use in the connection between the server and the client. Since I write code for both the server and the client in Android Studio, I believe this should be possible to implement.

Comment: you can specify set of suitable algorithms used for ssl connection by calling setEnabledCipherSuite

Comment: You only have to write one line of code to select the TLS cipher suite, and none of what you've written is it. Instead it is a separate implementation of encryption and digital signing. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you mean add the setEnabledCipherSuite for encryption @user207421?